# How can I use code-generated images on my WinRT live tile?

Tags: vb.net, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I'm trying to create live tiles in my app by using BitmapRender (in Windows 8.1) to create an image from a user control, which I then want to add as my live tile image.

Creating the image works perfectly, and I store it in the app's roaming folder. However, I can't get the image to add to the live tile *when created this way*. The odd thing is that if I copy my generated file into the project and then try to attach it to the live tile it works (so the image must be correctly formatted/size, etc.); and if I copy a random image into my roaming folder and set that as the live tile image it also works (meaning I am able to use a file in the roaming folder to set the tile image)...so that means I am referencing the file location correctly, and the image itself is capable of being used on a live tile...so why doesn't it work?

I have created a sample project (link below) that illustrates that my live tile creating code works (with an image stored in the project), and also that I can successfully create an image from a UI control and store it in the roaming folder (FWIW I've tried using different folders with no change in behaviour).

Is there something I'm missing? Any insight or help would be greatly appreciated.

Project is in VB.net, but I can figure out answers in C# if that's easier.

[Sample project to illustrate the issue](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=5AF059DA63BE71BC!155420&authkey=!AJTzkUZ92Oe2E-s&ithint=file,.zip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is that you're attempting to use an absolute file path to reference the image, which is not supported. If you look in the tile schema, specifically at the [page for the  element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212855.aspx), you'll see that the src must be an URI using http[s]://, ms-appx:///, or ms-appdata:///local for Windows Store apps. The fact that you can use a relative in-package path of /livetile.png is a bit of a fluke, as that's defaulting to ms-appx:///livetile.png.

What you need to do, then, is just use this for a filepath:

```
filepath = "ms-appdata:///local/livetile.png"
```

I tried this in your sample and it worked fine. Do note that only the local folder is supported here, not roaming. This is primarily because roaming appdata is limited to 100K to begin with, and dropping tile images in there would often quickly fill your quota. You'll want to then generate the image locally on each device (which would make sense also because you can then take the current scaling into account).

Comment: Kraig, thanks for your response. I actually figured this out over the weekend, but didn't get around to updating on here. Apart from needing to use the local folder, another issue gets in the way - Windows seems to stop updating the tile if you make a lot of changes in a short time period (which is typical when testing code).

Comment: I believe it has a kind of debounce algorithm built in for rapid updates. The best thing to do when testing is to make sure you clear the tile before issuing an update, as that should get the latest update to appear.

Comment: Unfortunately I was clearing the tile first. It lets me change it several times, then just stops updating. Not a huge deal now that I know what the issue was, but during testing it was quite frustrating!

Comment: I've written up a detailed blog post with a sample project for anyone who comes across this same issue. It's a really important thing to have in WinRT apps, but it's so tricky to implement. This technique only works in Windows 8.1; I'm still trying to figure out a way on Windows 8.0...[Creating Dynamic Live Tiles from UI Controls in Windows 8.1](http://pumpkinszwan.wordpress.com/2013/12/15/creating-dynamic-live-tiles-from-ui-controls-windows-8-1/)